# How to create a visual studio plugin that controls winamp?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, winamp

I often listen to music while I code.
Switching songs while in the middle of something damages your productivity because you have to move to another window.
How would you implement such a plug in and in what language would I be more comfortable with if I want to interact with the winamp sdk?
I'm a C++ programmer but I can get by with C# as well.

Comment: This is almost a SuperUser question :P. What's wrong with hotkeys? You can get it going in 2 minutes.

Comment: it is easier for sure configure some global shortcut for your favorite player (I did it for foobar2000), but the question is nice

Comment: How can I define a hotkey within Visual Stodio to control winamp?

Comment: Winamp (and most players) supports *global* hotkeys - these will work in VS and any other program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the Winamp SDK and should be really easy to make it in either C++ or C#. I had a similar problem and had made a addin for the same, it's not a full featured add in but takes care of the basics functionality.

And yes I knew of the global shortcuts before I developed it, sometimes you just are doing everything with the keyboard and don't want to switch to the mouse and sometimes you are using the mouse and don't want to go to the keyboard. It is just a very tiny thing for half a second increase in productivity!

You can make your own or give my addin a try if it fulfills your needs - http://www.tejasshirodkar.com/blog/2009/04/vswinamp-winamp-addon-for-visual-studio/

Comment: Is your add-in opensource?
Also it says I can't install it because the right installer is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Winamp already has a global hotkey plugin (And several 3rd party hotkey plugins)

As far as the [Winamp SDK](http://dev.winamp.com/wiki/Plug-in_Developer) goes, C/C++ is fine since the plugins are native dlls.